# Simple HTML layout for iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I am trying to prepare a simple layout design that would work on all devices. I am having issues with iPad at the moment. The whole webpage should not be scrollable, but iPad tries to force and scroll the website outside it's borders ( I think its called overlay scrolling, which give you a smoother feeling ). If the overlay scrolling persists, I do not really have an issue with that, but the main problem is:

- When I open the webpage and try to scroll the vertically scrollable content (white left content or red right content), the whole webpage scrolls and not the div itself.
- If I try to swipe to scroll the content, sometimes it works, sometimes the whole webpage scrolls again. It's totally unpredictable. Can someone help me make a plunker example?

[image: A simple layout example]

I think making a separate css file for mobile device will be necessary. Ofcourse we are using bootstrap in the first place.

Comment: Use bootstrap for responsive designs. You only need bootstrap CSS file (and your own to overwrite those styles if you want). http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Hey, ofcourse we are using bootstrap. The problem is still with scrolling content on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the media query for specific device this is for ipad in landscape or portrait mode ..try it once ..you can try this in same css file as well as in different file

```html
    @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

iPad in landscape

```html
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```